# React + Express - What to serve instead of /build when in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I used `create-react-app` to initialize my React app, and I am now serving the React client app from an Express server.

My app structure is

```
project/
  build/
  server/
  src/
```

where my Express server is in `server/`, my React app is in `src/`, and the React app gets built to `build/` with `npm run build`.

Because my Express app serves the "built" app (as shown below, serving files from the `build/` directory), I need to `npm run build` every time I change any client code, in order for my browser to reflect the changes.

```
// server/app.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');


const app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);


// Serve static assets

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));


// sockets

require('./sockets')(io);


// serve main file

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
});


module.exports = server;
```

Since the build step takes many seconds, this is obviously a big step down from when just serving the React app with `react-scripts start` and having it watch for code changes and instantly reflect them in the browser.

I know I can use `NODE_ENV === 'production'` to check if I'm on production or development, but given I'm on development, where are the files I should serve instead of the ones in `build/`?

I.e. perhaps a relevant question is "from where are they being served when I run the React server with `react-scripts start`"? EDIT: and how are they being watched such that building the source files to that spot is extremely quick?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, but what I realized to bypass this issue is that I only wanted to add the Express app for serving other purposes (e.g. to handle socket communication), it wasn't important for serving the React app itself. So I put the sections `// Serve static assets` and `// serve main file` in a `isProduction` if block (isProduction is based on NODE_ENV), and in development I instead have 2 servers running, the React dev server and the Express server, and the client makes all requests besides the initial one for index.html to the Express server instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the react boilerplates use [webpack dev server / browserify] + hot reload in dev mode, so your changes (and only your changes) are compiled on the fly and your browser is refreshed by a watcher.

It's basically a middleware you plug to express like that

```
var compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)

var devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
 publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
 quiet: true
})
app.use(devMiddleware)
```

It's done under the hood in your case, the files are written in memory.